# What vintage aircraft was registered as NC7210?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Can anyone help identify this vintage aircraft, origin, and possible flight history. Airplane has this number of its wing, NC 7210.

Comment: Do you have a picture of this airplane? Or more information? It's difficult to answer without more to go on.

Comment: @VtC - It seems pretty clear what's being asked. It may not have been asked well, but with (currently) 2 answers pointing at the same thing, it seems perfectly clear...

Comment: @FreeMan Registration numbers can be reused, can't they? So the plane identified by the two answers isn't necessarily the one the asker is thinking of.

Answer (score 6):

My step grandfather, Roy Danischefsky, purchased the Ryan B-1 Brougham #157 NC 7210 in Sept 1928 from Mahoney-Ryan Aeronautics for Midwest Airlines (Wisconsin). He flew it for Mid-West as a private charter and to promote flight as a new transportation option. Here is a photo of him in front of the plane.

Also - Here a photo of the plane from San Diego Air and Space Museum Archives

https://www.flickr.com/photos/sdasmarchives/5684139991/in/photostream/

Where is this plane now? I would be VERY EXCITED to know that it is still exists. Many of these planes did not survive.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE and thanks for sharing your story. If you want to know where this plane is now, it would be best to [ask](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) that as a separate question (you can link to this one for context).

Answer (score 4):

There is (or was) a [Ryan B-1 Brougham](https://yanksair.org/collection/ryan-b-1-brougham-2/) of construction number 157 registered as NC7210 according to [airhistory.org.uk](http://www.airhistory.org.uk/gy/reg_N16.html).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This registration record page](http://www.airhistory.org.uk/gy/reg_N16.html) says it's a Ryan B-1 Brougham.  That's the same company that built the Ryan Lindbergh flew solo across the Atlantic, though it's a different model aircraft.  The page linked says a couple aircraft of this model were used in a Lindberg movie, flown by the late Paul Mantz.